# How to fix 'time data does not match format'?

Tags: python

I am currently using Python to connect to a database.

In one of the tables, the format for date is: `2019/03/02` (`%Y-%m-%d`)

In the Python file I have:

```
startdate=datetime.strptime(request.form[('startdate')],'%Y-%m-%d')
enddate = datetime.strptime(request.form[('enddate')],'%Y-%m-%d')
```

In the webpage, when adding the dates: `2018/03/02` as `startdate` and `2019/03/02` as `enddate`, an error occurs:

```
timedata 2018/03/02 does not match format ('%Y-%m-%d').
```

The `datetime` module is imported in python.

Hence, can someone please explain how to fix this error?

Comment: Use slashes instead of minus signs in the format?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have done that, however now the error states: timedata does not match format '%y/%m/%d'

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a format that matches your data.

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) says:

> `%y`  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   `%Y`  Year with century as a decimal number.

Characters that are not prepended with `%` match themselves.

So the correct format would be `%Y/%m/%d`.